# Concerning the behavior of `do-release-upgrade` with and without `-d`

Tags: update-manager, do-release-upgrade

After doing `do-release-upgrade -d`, be it to upgrade to 20.04 *now* instead of whenever it will be made available or for other reasons, will this in anyway "stick around" and affect subsequent uses of `do-release-upgrade`? I.e. will the use of the `-d` flag alter some state of the system and implicitly enable `Prompt=` to somehow stick with "development release"?

> `-d`, `--devel-release` If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the
> development release

Let me give a concrete example.

- `do-release-upgrade` until a few days ago (haven't checked since) would not offer an upgrade to 20.04 from 18.04
- `do-release-upgrade -d` enables the upgrade to 20.04 even though this isn't officially sanctioned, yet
- I am using only LTS versions and I'd like to only hop between LTS versions

  - By default `do-release-upgrade` will support this exact mode of operation

    > Checking for a new Ubuntu release
    > There is no development version of an LTS available.
    > To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release
    > set `Prompt=normal` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.
- I now decide to make use of `do-release-upgrade -d` on a Ubuntu 18.04
- fast-forward and suppose we're in summer 2022 but before Canonical enables upgrades through `do-release-upgrade` (*without* `-d`) ... what will I get offered?

**To summarize:** will a single use of `-d` for an upgrade be persistent and affect subsequent uses of `do-release-upgrade`?

Answer (score 2):

About upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS - it is blocked by [some bugs](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-1-lts-point-release-status-tracking/17604). This is why we need `-d` here.

About next upgrades - you have to set back `Prompt=lts` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

The `update-manager` or `do-release-upgrade` will adjust their behaviour by reading above configuration file and `-d` option (if any) at next run time. So there are no worries here.

Comment: they'll adjust their behavior, but this adjustment won't persist, did I get you right?

Comment: The adjustment will not persist, right.